# VPN Bypass for Specific Services

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

Following [this example](http://themediaserver.com/codefile.php?t=vpn-bypass-exemple):

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter=0
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.tun0.rp_filter=0
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.lo.rp_filter=0 

sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.lo.forwarding=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.tun0.forwarding=1

sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eth0.forwarding=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.lo.forwarding=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.tun0.forwarding=1

sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_fwmark_accept=1

iptables -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t nat -F

ip route flush table 101
ip route flush cache

ip rule del fwmark 2 table 101
ip rule add fwmark 2 table 101

ip route add table 101 default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
ip route add table 101 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.102

iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 2
```

However, when I start OpenVPN and then log into my server with ssh and then run `last`, I see the IP of my VPN service, not my external IP.

What am I missing?

OS: Ubuntu 16.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

```
iptables -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t nat -F

echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter
echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/tun0/rp_filter
ip route flush table 101
ip rule add fwmark 2 table 101
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 table 101
ip route flush cache

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22    -j MARK --set-mark 2
```

In brief, `ip route flush cache` should go right after the last `ip route add` command, and for iptables, `OUTPUT` chain should be used instead of `PREROUTING`.